# xcode custom table cell doesn't align contents properly

Tags: xcode

I have created a custom table cell for an application. I arrange everything vertically to middle inside it, however when I run the application the labels are 50% outside the cell. How can I center the labels properly? My custom table cell has a height of 44px the view component inside the custom cell is also 44px in height.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Try giving `top` or, `buttom` space.

**Reason:-** It shows the content out of the cell boundary, though the contents are aligned in the center, maybe its because the alignment of the contents in *UILabel* itself is not centered or, its height is going beyond the expectation, as its top or buttom space is not provided.